# Finding the Maximum of a Function with numerical derivatives in R

Tags: r, optimization

I wish to numerically find the maximum of the function multiplied by Beta 3 shown on p346 of the following link when `tau=30`:

http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/papers/paper49/Diebold-Li.pdf

They give the answer on p347 as `0.0609`.

I would like to confirm this numerically in R. I.e. to take the derivative and find the value where it reaches zero.

```
library(numDeriv)

x <- 30
testh <- function(lambda){ ((1-exp(-lambda*30))/(lambda*30)) - exp(-lambda*30) }
grad_h <- function(lambda){
  val <- grad(testh, lambda)
  return(val^2)
}

OptLam <- optimize(f=grad_h, interval=c(0.0001,120), tol=0.0000000000001)
```

I take the square of the gradient as I want the minimum to be at zero.

Unfortunately, the answer comes back as Lambda=120!! With lambda at `120` the value of the objective function is `5.36e-12`.

By working by hand I can func a lower value of the numerical derivative that is closer to zero (it is also close to the analytical value given above):

```
grad_h(0.05977604)

## [1] 4.24494e-12
```

Why is the function above not finding this lower value? I have set the tolerance very high so it should be able to find such this optimal value?

Is it possible to correct the existing method so that it gives the correct answer?

Is there a better way to find the maximum gradient of a function numerically in R?
For example is there an optimizer that looks for zero rather than trying to find a minimum of maximum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `uniroot` to find where the derivative is 0.  This might work for you,

```
grad_h <- function(lambda){
    val=grad(testh,lambda)
    return(val)
}
## The root
res <- uniroot(grad_h, c(0,120), tol=1e-10)

## see it
ls <- seq(0.001, 1, length=1000)
plot(ls, testh(ls), col="salmon")
abline(v=res$root, col="steelblue", lwd=2, lty=2)
text(x=res$root, y=testh(res$root),
     labels=sprintf("(%f, %s)", res$root,
         format(testh(res$root), scientific = T)), adj=-0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: I squared the gradient because optimize() finds the minimum of a function so I was trying to get it to find the zero value instead!

Comment: Using uniroot which is designed to find the zero seems a much better option though

Comment: @Bazman with `optimize`, I'm not sure why there is trouble minimizing the derivative, but it seems to have no trouble with maximizing your function `testh`.